# Trying to improve logic for ninja, cowboy, bear game, but get unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

When I run this, I get **`unexpected identifier`** in Chrome (haven't tried others). It's related to generating the computer's choice, and I'm guessing the variable which I'm trying to create. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Or to solve the logic in a better way? I want the logic to be:

- First throw: more likely to be cowboy (middle road - similar to paper)
- Following throws based on user choices. Originally I planned on doing a check of a set of the user's previous choices, but I'm far from capable enough to code this. Hence, I opted to base it on only the last throw.

Here's the part of the code that doesn't work (wanted to paste the whole thing, but the formatting was a headache, and it was long). `var previoususerChoices` is created at the beginning of the script.

```
    var newComputerChoice = function () {
    if (previoususerChoices < array.length) {
        computerChoice = Math.random();
        //Change randomly generated number to ninja, cowboy, bear
        if (computerChoice < .25) {
            computerChoice = "ninja";
        } else if (computerChoice < .75) {
            computerChoice = "cowboy";
        } else {
            computerChoice = "bear";
        };
    } else {
        var previoususerChoice = previoususerChoices.slice(Math.max(arr.length -1,0));
        console.log(prevoususerChoice);
        if previoususerChoice === "ninja" {
            computerChoice = Math.random();
            if (computerChoice < .50) {
                computerChoice = "cowboy";
            } else if (computerChoice < .75) {
                computerChoice = "bear";
            } else {
                computerChoice = "ninja";
            }
        } else if previoususerChoice === "bear" {               
                if (computerChoice < .50) {
                    computerChoice = "ninja";
                } else if (computerChoice < .75) {
                    computerChoice = "cowboy";
                } else {
                    computerChoice = "bear";
                }
        } else {
                if (computerChoice < .50) {
                    computerChoice = "bear";
                } else if (computerChoice < .75) {
                    computerChoice = "cowboy";
                } else {
                    computerChoice = "ninja";              
                }
            }           
        }
    }   
    console.log('pc choice: ', computerChoice);
    }
```

UPDATE: I discovered the original problem was related to some missing parentheses. When that was fixed, a new problem occured:

```
previoususerChoices.push(userChoice);
```

When I'm trying to put the user's choice into an array (which is previously created), the Console tells me that `previoususerChoices.push` is not a function. I guess that's true, but I don't know any other way to push a value into an array, so I'm guessing that the real culprit is something else.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/36t25rn8/

Comment: A tip: There's a link at the right end of the error message line in the Chrome console. That link includes the line number the error occurred. If that doesn't help, click the link, Chrome shows you the exact error line. Or even better, use Firefox (with Firebug) to debug your code, it has far more understandable error messages.

Comment: After reviewing the code, I discovered that I had missed some parentheses. However, I know get a new error relating to pushing the user's choice into an array: previoususerChoices.push(userChoice);. According to the console, .push is not a function (which I guess is true), but it should work.

Comment: What the heck is `previoususerChoices < array.length` supposed to do? That line definitely doesn't work as you intended.

Comment: Supposed to check if the array holds a number or not. Since I created an empty array, the first pass should return this as true, running the conditional statement. On the next passes it should skip this step.

Comment: In the end, I opted out of the array solution. Now I just check the last user choice using a variable. It solved the problem, but renders me unable to add more advanced logic.